# I wonder if I can allocate a class to a particular member data and create an instance of that class

Tags: c++

I want to know whether it is possible or not.

I have a class in one project.

```
    class A { ...
    void CreateInternal(void);
    B* m_pData;
    ... }

void A::CreateInternal(void)
{
  m_pData= new B;
}
```

and in other project, i add C class and want to make it in A::CreateInernal(void) like this...

```
void A::CreateInternal(void)
{
  m_pData = new C; // ex) B is base class of C
}
```

Of course, i can make Class A to template class, however, i do not want it. I want to use it last. ( Suppose that dependency or other build error is free )

```
    typename<class T>
    class A { ...
    void CreateInternal(void);
    T* m_pData
        ... }

    void A<T>::CreateInternal(void)
    {
       m_pData = new T;
    }
```

I just want to register Class B or Class C in Class A.
Is it possible??

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: You can erase the type and store `void*` but then you need to preserve the type information elsewhere.  If `B` and `C` have a common base class, you can also store a pointer to that base.

Comment: Alternatively you could pass in a flag to CreateInternal to specify whether you are creating B or C. Though for whatever reason it looks like you want to avoid passing arguments in to CreateInternal()

Comment: It is possible to have those two implementations of `A::CreateInternal()` in two different Projects. However, it's not clear from your post how you wish to use `pData`. There might be a different/better implementation depending on how you are planning on using `pData`.

Comment: Your best option will depend on what you want to do with the `pData` pointer. Presumably it gets used somewhere outside the duration of the one `CreateInternal` function?

Comment: In that case, your best option is probably a class template.

Comment: I am sorry, actually, pData is member data in Class A. pData -> m_pData in Class A. and the type of m_pData' is base class of B and C. and m_pData is not used in outside.

Comment: I want to use flag. However, Class A has to know B and C. i don't want it, because it makes mutual reference(?). is it possible to new C in CreateInenral Class A without information about C? if Class A is template class, then i think it is possible... But if Class A is not template class, it makes error in build time.

Comment: I want to register Class C to a particular member data in Class A. So after i make A instance, i register C to the member data, and do CreateInternal().

Comment: Please use a descriptive title, readers should have some idea what you're asking about.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll be careful from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As denoted in the comments:

1. You don't want to make A a template class.
2. You the classes you want to create instances of share a common base class, which is the type of the member pointer as well (precondition for the following!).

So you can make `createInternal` a template *function* instead:

```
template <typename T>
void A::createInternal()
//   ^^^ A still is a normal class!
{
    m_data = new T();
    // (will fail if T is a different type NOT inheriting
    // from the base class in question)
}
```

Side note: Normally, if template functions are provided inside classes, you would have to [implement them in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1312382) (typically at least, there are ways around...), if `createInstance` is *private*, though, and you *don't call it from public inline functions*, you can safely implement it in the source file as well as this file will be the only location the template ever is used.

You can even go a step further and allow to call *all* possible constructors by use of a variadic template:

```
template <typename T, typename ... TT>
void A::createInternal(TT&& ... tt)
{
    m_data = new T(std::forward(tt)...);
    // (will fail, if there is no matching constructor
    // for the arguments provided)
}
```

OK, you now have to specify which instance you want to create:

```
void A::f()
{
    createInternal<B>();
    createInternal<C>();
}
```

I assume this being acceptable as you *need* to be able to tell somehow which type you actually want to create.

The alternative would be different functions for different classes (`createInternalB`, `createInternalC`), but that certainly is less elegant.

Side note:

> Is it possible??

Even if your classes did *not* share a common base class, you still could store your objects created in a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or, if you happen to compile pre-C++11, even in a union (but you need to take care yourself about which type actually is stored – in this respect, `std::variant` is just much safer, so prefer it whenever possible).

*Update on new comments:*

If you want to be able to create arbitrary objects within A without having to know which one actually is created, now offering two further alternatives:

In first variant you could make `createInternal` virtual in A (possibly even pure virtual) and then override in derived classes to provide the objects suiting your needs.

In second variant you provide an instance of some object provider class; assuming `D` is the base class of both `B : public D` and `A : public D`, so then the solution might look similar to this:

```
class A
{
public:
    class ObjectProvider
    {
    public:
        virtual ~ObjectProvider() = default;
        public: virtual D* createInstance() = 0;
    };
    template <typename T>
    class TheObjectProvider : public ObjectProvider
    {
        public:
        D* createInstance() override
        {
            return new T();
        }
    };

    A(std::unique_ptr<ObjectProvider> p)
        : objectProvider(std::move(p))
    { }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ObjectProvider> objectProvider;
    std::unique_ptr<D> m_data;

    void createInternal()
    {
        m_data = objectProvider->createInstance();
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
A ab(std::make_unique<A::ObjectProvider<B>());

// your own custom object provider:
class OP : public A::ObjectProvider
{
public:
     C* createInstance() override { return new C(); }
};
A ac(std::make_unique<OP>());
```

The `std::unique_ptr` as parameter (although in general, it is not recommended to use smart pointers for) now has an important function: It indicates that the class will take ownership of the object passed, i. e. is a sink in Herb Sutter's wording – see his [GotW91](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/)).

If you have a most commonly used data type (e. g. `B`), you could provide an overloaded default constructor providing an object provider for this type (or possibly the base type `D`, if not being abstract).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to study about  std::variant. And.. If i make createInternal to template function, when i call this, i have to insert createInternal<B> or createInternal<C>, right? then, it can make mutual reference because A, B and C are located in difference project. It is my fault that I inaccurately asked.

Comment: The CreateInternal() is called in a member function of Class A

Comment: `std::variant` is an option if you don't have a common base class (which you did not mention in the question itself). If you want to be able to store *any* object, there additionally is [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). Coming back to your comments, then better stick with the base class pointer, that will be much easier...